# Add code to <head> for specific content type

Tags: theming, display-suite

What would be the best way to add code inside the  tag of specific content type?

Display Suite is being used for layout and we are using a custom theme. Have created html.html.twig. If I add anything to the head tags of this file, of course, it shows on all the pages.

Can we create a separate template such as html--content-type.html.twig then add the code there?

If not what would be the Drupal way of adding this code to the head tags for only specific content type?

```
<script async 
   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
   <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3********",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The quick way

and maybe some will call it **dirty** way would be to add in your `THEMENAME.theme` file

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {  
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    // You can get nid and anything else you need from the node object.
    $vars["content_type"] = $node->bundle();
  }
}
```

and then in your `html.html.twig`

```
{% if content_type == "page" %}
  <script> ... </script>
{% endif %}
```

### alternatively

you can just put it in a .js file and include like this

```
function my_module_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // To get around the issue of D8 core escaping inline js we cram our js
  // file into a twig variable for printing "raw" in "html.html.twig" like so: 
  // {{ my_module_script|raw }}
  $variables['my_module_script'] = '<script type="text/javascript">' . file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/js/script.js') . '</script>';
}
```

as described in this [comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2391025#comment-12478988)

### proper way is probably to

Define a library and then to attach it following [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/add-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module)